# Where can I store the images for my android app?

Tags: flutter, dart, backend

I am building an app in flutter and I want to store many images. So will anyone suggest me where I can store the images which is easy to use in my app. I mean should I store it locally or in cloud? If yes which cloud or backend should I use, whichone is good and fully optimized for my flutter app (like mongo, django, firebase etc. ). Will anyone suggest me the best?

Anyone kind of help is appreaciated as I have no prior knowledge about the production part....

Answer (score 2):

Storing Images on a server can be very expensive, since the file sizes are very large compared to the usual data. So if you do not NEED to store them on a server, don't.

Storing images locally is pretty simple. You will want to use the path_provider package https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider . I ll post a function I am using in my current project that does this. You ll see, its pretty simple.

Note: In my Code I pull the file from my server. Obviously leave that part out if you are getting your images from a different source.

```
  Future<File> createFileOfPdfUrl(String fileLocation, String name) async {
    final url = Helper.baseUrl + "Files/Newsletter/" + fileLocation;

    final filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    var request = await HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse(url));
    var response = await request.close();

    var bytes = await consolidateHttpClientResponseBytes(response);
    String dir = (await pathProvider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
    File file = new File('$dir/$filename');
    await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);

    return file;
  }
```

Comment: where this package store files ? will these files will be available for everyone when I publish this app to play store? and what is maximum size I can store here?

Comment: @Sachin it stores it in whatever directory you get. In my case pathProvider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory get the apps document directory. Not sure what you mean by the second part. The files are being saved locally on the device, so other devices cannot access them.

Comment: In second part I just want to ask,  imagine if I have images of about 250 MB in size, will these images will still available to everyone after I build apk and provide this build apk to others